# How do I read the wind direction in Flight Simulator X?

Tags: flight-simulator-x

I can't work out the wind direction in an airport in Flight Simulator X while looking at the airport in map view. For example does 'Wind at 196°' mean that the wind is *coming* from 196° or is *going* to 196°?

Answer (score 2):

The direction the wind is reported in tells you **where the wind is coming from**.

Answer (score 0):

Via the ATIS you can get the information where the wind is coming from, I mostly use the airbus a320 and than I can make an estimate guess from where it is coming by using my GPS. And what it means if the say 'Wind at 196°'than it is coming towards you
[Cockpit link](https://uploadpie.com/FYo7Mb)